# How to process multiple select element values in a django form

Tags: python, django, forms

Hello python/django newbie here, please i am trying to build an application that collects short messages from users and displays them. but first i have to validate the messages to confirm they don't contain illegal text/contents. here is the problem, i have created an admin section such that admin logs in to validate posted messages, about 10 messages waiting for approval are displayed like so:

```
<form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />   
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100">ID</td>
                    <td width="150">Name</td>
                    <td>Content</td>
                    <td>Approve</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {% for ad in pendingAds %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ad.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ad.adName}}</td>
                        <td>{{ad.adText}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <select>
                                <option>pending</option>
                                <option>approved</option>
                                <option>disapproved</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}                                     
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" />   
        </form>
```

How do i process each n number of form select elements with their various values, when it is submitted to the view handling it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```
for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
    if key.startswith('adstatus_') and value == 'approved':
        id = key.split('_')[1]
        # there you can publish advert
```

For this work you need modify your template:

```
<select name="adstatus_{{ad.id}}">
    <option value="pending">pending</option>
    <option value="approved">approved</option>
    <option value="disapproved">disapproved</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can make `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ ad.id }}">` and use for select `name="status[{{ ad.id }}]"`.

Then, in back-end you can process request:

```
id_list = request.POST.getlist('id')
status_dict = {id:request.POST.get('status[{}]'.format(id)) for id in id_list}
```